# Fetch customer Id using email & Create new Google Ads Manager account

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm using Google Ads API PHP library in my system. But I didn't found following 2 API's in provided API list here https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/account-management/create-account:

1. API to find out whether user has already exist Google Ads account using email? If found then returns his 10 digit customer ID.
2. If user Google Ads account not found then create new Google Ads account (manager account on behalf of customer through our PHP script). So that after creating, I can link it under my manager account.

I have seen same process on few sites. Whenever user visits system, he entering his email address, name, etc.. then script searches for his existing Google Ads account if found return customer id or some data & auto logged-in to system otherwise creates new Google Ads manager account for him.

Please let me know any API or solution for these 2 cases.

Answer (score 0):

1- You can use https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/account-management/get-account-hierarchy  to find out all the ads account under the manager account. 
2- You can use https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/account-management/create-account to create google ad account under manager account